# returning DenseVector from UDF(numpy) error -pyspark

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I have a pyspark dataframe that looks like this and I want to use the `np.median()` function on it:

```python
+--+---------+
|id|   vector|
+--+---------+
| 1|[0,1,0,1]|
| 1|[0,0,0,1]|
| 2|[1,0,0,1]|
+--+---------+

root                                                                            
 |-- id: long (nullable = true)
 |-- vector: vector (nullable = true)
```

I then group the dataframe by `id` and make a list of vectors out of the `vectors` column.

```python
df = df.groupBy('id').agg(F.collect_list("vector").alias("vector_list"))
```

This is the resulting dataframe:

```python
+--+---------------------+
|id|          vector_list|
+--+---------------------+
| 1|[[0,1,0,1],[0,0,0,1]]|
| 2|            [1,0,0,1]|
+--+---------------------+
```

Now I want to apply the following `UDF`:

```python
@F.udf(VectorUDT())
def udf_find_median(vec: Vector):
    return DenseVector(np.median(vec, axis=0))

df = df.withColumn('vector', udf_find_median(F.col('vector_list')).drop('vector_list')
```

This is the expected output:

```python
+--+-----------+
|id|vector_list|
+--+-----------+
| 1|[0,0.5,0,1]|
| 2|  [1,0,0,1]|
+--+-----------+
```

But I get the following error:

```python
TypeError: cannot serialize DenseVector([0,0.5,0,1]) of type <class 'pyspark.mllib.linalg.DenseVector'>
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Can you print the schema for the original data frame ?

Comment: @Psidom updated the question

Comment: This seems to work for me. Maybe you could try `Vectors.dense` instead of `DenseVector`.

Comment: Try using 'pyspark.ml.linalg.DenseVector' instead of 'pyspark.mllib.linalg.DenseVector'